# Reject not working in chain with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

In my app I'm receiving packages from usb device. After i send command i should call receive function every `N` ms to get all packets.

I created chain with promises:

```
var packagesCount = 10;
var chain = $q.when();
for (var i=0; i<packagesCount; i++) {
    chain = chain.then(hidRead((packagesCount-i)*1000));
}

chain.then(function () {
    console.log("all finished")
}, function (reason) {
    console.log(reason);
    console.log(reason)
});
```

And my read function that contains two `async` functions:

```
function hidRead(ms) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (self.connectionId) {
            chrome.hid.receive(self.connectionId, function (reportId, data){
                console.log(data);
                defer.resolve();
            });
        } else {
            defer.reject(new Error('Connection failed'));
        }

    }, ms);

    return function() {
        return defer.promise;
    };
}
```

And my `fail` function called only after all `Timeouts` functions done. But i need to reject it immediately. If we lost connection, and get reject we should stop chain execution.

I tried add `catch`, fail callbacks in loop, anything helped.

Comment: Do you really want to run all of these in parallel? If so, then use `Promise.all` instead of the chaining, if not, you should put the  promise creation and the `setTimeout` inside the function returned by  `hidRead(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi no, i don't need parallel. I need call one by one with interval `N` ms

Comment: @Bergi but i need to make sure that previous was success to call another

Comment: @Bergi when i put inside function, it never called, or if i call it in loop, "finished" message print first

Comment: If it is never called, that suggests that `chrome.hid.receive` never calls its callback. Please show that attempt, and put some logs in it to tell us where exactly it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidRead` just recreates the functionality of `$timeout`, but the problem is that `hidRead` is called on chain creation, this means that all timeouts will be unconditionally executed. To avoid this, `hidRead` should return callback function.

If `chrome.hid.receive(...)` is not asynchronous or the delay is never higher than `ms`, it is basically something like

```
function hidRead(ms) {
  return function () {
    return $timeout(function () {
      if (self.connectionId) {
        chrome.hid.receive(self.connectionId, function (reportId, data){
          console.log(data);
        });
      } else {
        return $q.reject(new Error('Connection failed'));
      }    
    });      
  }
}
```

Otherwise, `$q.defer()` may be additionally used, and original code changes to

```
function hidRead(ms) {
  return function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(...);
    return defer.promise;
  }
}
```

The code above will trigger a digest on each iteration. If this is not necessary or creates performance issues, `$q` may be changed to native `Promise` or Bluebird, the latter has `Promise.delay` which is useful in such scenarios.

Comment: `chrome.hid.receive` is asynchronous function, and i tried to put Timeout into callback function. It didn't work because nothing happens. I added `()` to `chain = chain.then(hidRead((packagesCount-i)*1000)());` then "finished" message i get first

Comment: Then you have problems not with the subject but with `chrome.hid.receive`, the callback is not triggered or whatever. The flow control here is really straightforward, it's like the answer explains.

Comment: But do i need call function that i return ?

Comment: No. You return a callback, it is called by `then` chain, this is the final goal of the whole thing here. I would suggest to add another `setTimeout(() => $q.reject('timeout error'), 10000))` next to first setTimeout, in the case if the chain stalls for some reason.

Comment: oh, yes you are right. I just need change time `(packagesCount-i)*1000` in reverse order